# Regarding Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am very new to Spring Batch. I just tried to run a simple spring batch example which i got from net in vain.The example just tries to read from a flat file and write the contents into a separate flat file.

Below is my xml which is loaded into context (through a ContextLoaderListener).

test-batch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://172.18.7.57/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
<bean id="simpleJob"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJo b">
<property name="name" value="simpleJob" />
<property name="steps">
<list>
<ref local="step" />
</list>
</property>
<property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.suppo rt.SimpleJobLauncher">
<property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.s upport.SimpleJobRepository">
<constructor-arg>
<bean
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.d ao.MapJobInstanceDao" />
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<bean
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.d ao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<bean
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.d ao.MapStepExecutionDao" />
</constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.batch.support.transacti on.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="step"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.Si mpleStepFactoryBean">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
<property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
<property name="itemReader" ref="itemReader" />
<property name="itemWriter" ref="itemWriter" />
</bean>


<bean id="lineAggregator"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transfo rm.DelimitedLineAggregator">
<property name="delimiter" value="|" />
</bean>

<bean id="itemWriter"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFil eItemWriter">
<property name="fieldSetCreator" ref="fieldSetMapper" />
<property name="lineAggregator" ref="lineAggregator" />
<property name="resource" value="file:/hello2.txt" />
</bean>

<bean id="lineTokenizer"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transfo rm.DelimitedLineTokenizer" />

<bean id="fieldSetMapper"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping .PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />

<bean id="itemReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFil eItemReader">
<property name="resource" value="file:/hello1.txt" />
<property name="lineTokenizer" ref="lineTokenizer" />
<property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="fieldSetMapper" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

As i dont have maven, i tried launching this job from my java code like ,

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("D:\\jboss-4.0.5.GA\\server\\default\\deploy\\test.war\\WEB-INF\\xml\\test-batch.xml");

Job job;

job = (Job) context.getBean("simpleJob");
JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersConverter.getJobParameters(StringUtils
.splitArrayElementsIntoProperties(new String[]{"D:\\jboss-4.0.5.GA\\server\\default\\deploy\\venki.war\\WEB-INF\\xml\\venki-batch.xml","simpleJob"}, "="));

JobExecution jobExecution = launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

--But, some error is thrown in eclipse saying no class loaders found....below is the error i got....

```
org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deseria lize(SerializationUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deseria lize(SerializationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJ obExecutionDao.copy(MapJobExecutionDao.java:33)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJ obExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(MapJobExecutionDao .java:56)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support. SimpleJobRepository.saveOrUpdate(SimpleJobReposito ry.java:216)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support. SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRe pository.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.Simp leJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:79)
    at com.venki.handler.TestHandler.testSpringBatch(Test Handler.java:111)
```

--Please help me in this regard...i need to find out a code that reads from a flat file and inserts into a DB....i need to integrate this into a stand alone module and i should not go with using maven....

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you run it by using `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner` 
you can define it as your main class in **Run Configuration** of eclise.
In Arguments give

```
<your batch-job-xml-file><space><your Job (in your case its simpleJob)>
```

You dont need maven here too. Just set classpath of required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The sample Spring Batch football project reads from a CSV file and write into a database using JDBC.

You can find the details [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/trunk/spring-batch-samples/#football), and the download links are at the top of that page.

As far as Maven goes, you don't need it, but you'll have to manually include all the required libraries on your classpath. If you're running it through Eclipse, trigger the `CommandLineJobRunner`.